# can't align text in the scrollable label

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make a scrollable chat panel whose texts start from bottom but when `size_hint_y` is set to `None` it seem we can't align text to bottom and texts start from top.

Here is my scrollable label:

```
ScrollView:
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgb:0,0,1/20.0,1
    Rectangle:
      size:self.size
      pos:self.pos
  Label:
    line_height:1
    spacing:3
    markup:True
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    width: self.width
    text: root.manager.chatLog
    halign:"left"
    valign:"bottom"
    text_size: self.width, None
    font_size:sp(25)
    font_name: "Odin Rounded - Bold.otf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you probably want to add textlines sequentially to the scrollview. ScrollView only accepts 1 widget. So you have to specify a layout. For example in your kv part you could have the following:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1,1
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: chat_logs
            cols: 1
            padding: dp(8)
            spacing: dp(4)
            row_default_height: dp(14)
```

Then in your python part:

```
chattext = "the chat line you received or want to send"
chatmess = Label(text=chattext, markup=True, height=dp(12), size_hint=(1,None))
self.chat_logs.add_widget(chatmess)
```